# Consent Screen still being verified

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-platform, google-calendar-api, google-oauth

I'm developing an Windows application that uses the Google Calendar API, already filled in all the informations in the "Consent Screen" page and sent to verification. After 3 days I received an e-mail saying:

> Verification not required. Your app is not required to go through verification at this time. We will be closing out this request and there will be no impact on your app.

After 2 weeks, my consent screen page is still saying "Your consent screen is being verified." and the logo I choosed does not appear in the OAuth Screen. Any ideias of what is happening? Do I need to wait longer?

Answer (score 4):

You must list one or more sensitive scopes in the under the **Scopes for Google APIs** section of [your OAuth consent screen](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/consent) so that Google knows which scopes to verify.

I've created a screencast showing the process to [add the `../auth/contacts.readonly` scope to an OAuth project here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2RCMNrTMa44&t=48). You should be able to use it as a reference to add the sensitive scopes you are accessing via API.

When you have added a sensitive scope, you'll see a warning asking you to verify your app, like here: [image: sensitive scopes for Google APIs]